# How can i use USSD Code in python using ADB and PYautogui

Tags: python, python-3.x, adb, pyautogui

I used ADB and pyautogui, but when I run the code, it opens the phone app and calls the number that contains the USSD code instead of using it as a code. Also, when the call connects, the hash symbol (#) at the end of the number does not appear, even though I added it in Python. Is there a solution or any help, please? I am a beginner in Python. Thank you.

I want to use USSD code using Python.
my code:

```
phone_number = "*133*" + str(random.randint(100, 999)) + "#"

pyautogui.typewrite(f"adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:{phone_number}")
```

Answer (score 0):

USSD codes are different from regular phone calls, so you cannot use the `CALL` intent.
Instead, you should open the dialer and enter all the symbols and numbers using the following adb commands -

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.DIAL
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_STAR
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_1
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_3
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_3
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_STAR
// The other random digits one by one
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_POUND
```

After pressing the last pound (or hash) symbol, the USSD call will be made.

Answer (score 0):

**Instead Of:**
`phone_number = "*133*" + str(random.randint(100, 999)) + "#"`

**Use:**
`phone_number = "*133*" + str(random.randint(100, 999)) + "%23"`

**"%23"** will be replaced with "#" hence normal CALL can be used for USSDs.